# Limit of $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^{\sin(x)}}{\ln(\ln(x))}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We want to find the limit of

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^{\sin(x)}}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\sin(x)} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(\ln(x)) = \infty$

I tried using 'Hospital here, which leads to

$$\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\sin\left(x\right)}\cos\left(x\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x\ln\left(x\right)}}$$

but that also cannot be evaluated.

But if we insert the limit of our original function, we get this:
[image]

Can someone explain, how one can apply the squeeze theorem here or solve this with another approach?

Comment: Start with what you should know like $ -1\le \sin(x) \le 1$

Comment: What makes you think $\lim e^{\sin x} = \infty$?  You need that to be true to justify using L'Hopital's Rule, so you need to justify that step.  (You'll find that you can't, because it's not true.)

Comment: @RobertShore Oh sorry, I wasn't thinking. $e^{\sin(x)}$ is actually indeterminate, so we can't use L'Hospital here

Comment: What two numbers can you squeeze it between.

Comment: They both go toward 0 forcing it to be $0$.

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$ one of the has $e$ to a negative $1$ power the other just $e$. this is because of what @hamam_Abdallah mentioned to you.

Comment: +1 for your try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Claim:** $$\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{e^{\sin x}}{\ln(\ln(x))}=0.$$

**Proof of claim:**

Since $\sin x$ has a minimum value of $-1$ and a maximum value of $1$, You have that

$$\frac{1}{e \ln(\ln(x))} \le \frac{e^{\sin x}}{\ln(\ln(x))}\le \frac{e}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$

holds for every $x \to \infty$, forcing the limit to be $0$
To see this note $\frac{1}{e \ln(\ln(x))}, \frac{e}{\ln(\ln(x))}$ both tend to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. $\blacksquare$